# split pandas column prepending with actual column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

> ```
> >>>table1
>          col1      col2
> row1      A         A
> row2      B         A
> row3      A         B
> row4      B         A
> ```
>
> I want to convert only one column in the above dataframe into following DataFrame using one-hot expression or any other methods
>
> ```
> >>>table1
>          col1_A    col1_B    col2
> row1      1         0         A
> row2      0         1         A
> row3      1         0         B
> row4      0         1         A
> ```
>
> Thank you in advance

Comment: Chekout pandas.get_dummies https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: yep it worked , but i want it this way (edited) @SahilDahiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be `get_dummies` + `concat` -

```
df
     col1 col2
row1    A    A
row2    B    A
row3    A    B
row4    B    A
```

```
i = pd.get_dummies(df.col1, prefix='col1')
j = df.drop('col1', axis=1)  # remove the column being OHE'd, thanks to the English puppy.

pd.concat([i, j], 1)

      col1_A  col1_B col2
row1       1       0    A
row2       0       1    A
row3       1       0    B
row4       0       1    A
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.get_dummies`

```
In [211]: pd.get_dummies(table1)
Out[211]:
      col1_A  col1_B  col2_A  col2_B
row1       1       0       1       0
row2       0       1       1       0
row3       1       0       0       1
row4       0       1       1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":['A','B']*2,'col2':['A','A','B','A']},index=['row1','row2','row3','row4'])
df

      col1  col2
row1    A   A
row2    B   A
row3    A   B
row4    B   A
```

Apply get_dummies only on the column you want and then merge back with the data frame having rest of the columns

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.loc[:,"col1"]).join(df.loc[:,"col2"])
df1

        A   B   col2
row1    1   0   A
row2    0   1   A
row3    1   0   B
row4    0   1   A
```

Answer (score 0):

Let use some column selection and `pd.get_dummies` and `assign` to join back to dataframe.

```
df[['col2']].assign(**pd.get_dummies(df[['col1']]))
```

Output:

```
     col2  col1_A  col1_B
row1    A       1       0
row2    A       0       1
row3    B       1       0
row4    A       0       1
```